# Azure SQL Data Sync No Response

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I started to run Azure SQL Data Sync to an empty DB, from Azure SQL Database to another Azure SQL Database in the same Azure SQL Server, however, it found that the Sync State no response for more than 2 days, there is no any new data insert or process, the Status still show Processing

I can see there are many tables and records sync there successfully, the DB size is 100GB and all tables completed, except 1 table, the source has about 100 million records, and the destination table close to 100 million records but stuck for 2 days

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

100 million records is a lot of records for an Initial Sync. Since there is data on the source database, as well as the target database, Data Sync will undergo a row-by-row conflict resolution process which is very slow. What I suggest is

1. Remove the tables/large tables from the Sync Schema
2. Truncate the tables/large tables on the target database
3. Add the tables/target tables to the Sync Schema.
4. Sync.

By doing the above steps, you will be asking Data Sync to BULK INSERT the 100 million records from the source database tables/large table to the target database tables/large table, directly.
Since there would be zero rows in the tables/large table on the target database, there would not conflicts, and BULK INSERT will happen.

Comment: Thanks, The current status is Tombstone cleanup completed successfully. 0 rows deleted., should I stop the Sync and start again?

Comment: Yes, we will have to stop any running Sync before following the steps that I mentioned. I am assuming that the Sync still would not have been completed.

Comment: Thanks, after stop the sync and restart again, all work and sync finally completed without error